# Badges not being received

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, badges

I should've received these badges, but haven't. Is this because the system is overloaded as it is has just started?

- Scholar
- Student
- Teacher
- Autobiographer
- Mortarboard
- Precognitive
- Custodian
- Editor
- Supporter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stack Exchange staff has activated the necessary scheduled jobs and badges are awarded [right now as we speak](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/help/badges). That does not surprise me, but the interesting part is that the awardance timestamps have been backdated. Well done!

Comment: Great, thanks! Just gained 17 badges!

Answer (score 6):

Badges take a while to receive. I would not be concerned for at least another 24 hours.

Edit: [I just got the "informed" badge 23 seconds ago.](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/help/badges/84/informed?userid=8)

Comment: FYI, the Informed badge is awarded instantly, which is [an exception](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164073/295232). Other badges still haven't been awarded.

Comment: @Glorfindel Sorry to be a pain, but do we know when they will start to be awarded?

Comment: @taylor.2317 I suspect a SE developer has to poke the relevant scheduled tasks.

Comment: @Glorfindel Okay, thanks for all ur help :)