# Close vote reviews are not triggered

Tags: bug, status-completed, review

Perhaps related to [Badges not being received](https://proofassistants.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11/4) – the question [How often can Proof Assistants be used in everyday life?](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/q/26/4) got some close votes, but an hour later it still hasn't appeared in the close review queue. Normally, this happens about fifteen minutes after the first close vote.

Comment: I just reviewed an item in the Reopen Queue .

Comment: @HenryWHHackv3.0b right ... perhaps it's just the CV queue suffering from this bug. Reopen votes [immediately trigger the queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370896/295232) since a while.

Comment: Report received - passed it along internally. Might take a moment to get to (not the most urgent fix right at the start).

Comment: It's showing  now. Happy reviewing!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apologies for the inconvenience, and thanks for your patience, y'all. This was a fun one.

The Close Votes queue and some of the others are refreshed on a schedule. The Scheduler service is configured to discover new sites when they join the network (and, in general, new scheduled routes when they're added to the code). This works perfectly unless you somehow end up with the Scheduler deployed with dev tier config instead of production. You'd think that everything else would fail catastrophically in that situation, but no - because the config is also cached. :P

So the Scheduler was happily running and updating for all sites that it was aware of, but didn't pick up either Proof Assistants or Substrate. The immediate configuration issue has been resolved. I'll be following up with folks internally to figure out how we even ended up in this situation and how to prevent it going forward.

Comment: Hi @Adam, I am also aware that the "Suggested edits" queue has a lot of pending edits to review, but every time I click on it, I am told that "the review is cleared" even though it is clearly not. Do you know what might be going on there?

Comment: @NikeDattani Do you mean tag edits? If so you need more reps to review those. 750 reps you only have 501 reps.

Comment: @HenryWHHackv3.0b When I click on the review queue, it has a red circle around "suggested edits" yet no reviews are available to me. Maybe you are right that the red circle is only there to indicate that tag edits are pending.

Comment: @NikeDattani I'll double-check tomorrow, but Henry's theory sounds plausible. Being able to tailor review queue indicators to individual users is unfortunately hard with the way we have the whole thing set up. Normally it's mildly confusing/annoying, but can definitely be more pronounced on a brand new site.

Comment: @AdamLear Yes, I've noticed on a few sites that when I click on the review queue button, there's a red circle next to some of the items, but then when I click on that item to do the reviews, it says the review is already cleared, even though the red circle remains there for hours. Perhaps it's because I don't have permission to review those specific edits that are in the review queue.

Comment: Adam, I've now reviewed all tag wiki edits and 0 remain in the queue, however the red circle still appears when I click the reviews button on the main site. CC @HenryWHHackv3.0b

Comment: [This first-question](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/q/485/8) didn't show up in the review queue, even though there's been only 5 views and 0 activity on it (hence no one reviewed it yet). On other sites such questions seem to show up immediately in the review queue. Does it take longer on this site than other sites, for the review queue to refresh?

Answer (score 1):

This is a guess, but I think that **three** close votes need to be submitted first.

In the case of [my question](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/26/how-often-can-proof-assistants-be-used-in-everyday-life), it got flagged for being a duplicate ***before*** it got 3 close votes.

Comment: No, usually just one flag or vote is sufficient (source: hanging around various Stack Exchange sites for 6+ years) ...

Comment: Oh, didn't know this. Maybe the system hasn't been put in place properly ***yet***?

Comment: It's been a while since sites entered private beta, but these kind of startup problems are not unfamiliar...